# Old network login passed to IIS

Tags: windows, iis, asp.net, domain, authentication

Let me start by saying that I am not a server guy - I am a developer. But I develop and manage an ASP.NET application that uses Windows authentication. I've run into the problem I am about to describe before, and I would just like to understand how to remedy it since I am the one who always gets the original support request.

A user, let's call her JaneDoe, has just gotten married and her login has been changed to JaneJones. We have an application that uses Windows authentication to store the user's login name to a table and then redirects the user to another non-Windows authenticated site with a GUID which points to the table entry we just made. When the user reaches the second site, we read in the login name from the database using the GUID that was passed. Then, we look up the login name in another database where we track application permissions.

The problem is that the user is logging into her workstation as JaneJones, but the Windows authenticated site is still receiving a login name of JaneDoe. Is this a domain controller issue? Is it a workstation issue? What's the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Could it be a browser cookie issue?

Comment: @Jon - I doubt it. I am certain our help desk team has probably already had this user clear her cookies and reboot her workstation - all the normal baseline attempts at fixing weird issues. I think it has something to do with her network credentials being cached out on the network possibly, but that is why I am trying to see if anyone is familiar with this very specific scenario. I will double check on the cookie clearing though JIC.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Login name was changed and not the display name? You can check her log on name on her pc by

Start -> Run -> cmd  ->OK

In the CMD window type

```
  set username
```

This shows her windows userid. If normal Windows authenication is used with IE, this is the user id being presented to Webserver. If you IIS logging, this is the same ID you will see in the log.

Answer (score 0):

If you've confirmed that the username really was changed (see ggonsalv's suggestion), double check to make sure the user didn't check the IE box to save the password.  Follow these steps:

- Control Panel
- User Accounts
- Click the Advanced Tab
- Manage Passwords

If you see the server address you're trying to connect to in there, select it, and click remove.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I've seen this before with IIS 6. Turns out there's a token cache external to the W3WP instance, so restarting that (i.e. recycling) doesn't help; I can't remember the details, but either an IISReset or a whole-server restart is required to clear it.